# How to use primitive types in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, jvm

Kotlin automatically forces us to use wrappers like Float, Double, Int, Boolean, etc.

But sometimes, for performance and memory reasons, we need to use primitive types.

I am aware that this can be done if you use special arrays such as IntArray, DoubleArray, FloatArray, etc.

But what about single primitives in a variable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Kotlin doesn't use wrapper types for non-nullable types, such as `Int` or `Float` - those will get compiled into `int` and `float`. However, if you use nullable types, such as `Int?` or `Float?`, Kotlin will use wrapper types - `Integer` and `Float` - to be able to represent null values. Using non-nullable primitive types in Kotlin will not lead to unnecessary allocations.